# How to respond when someone praises about my Japanese?

Tags: politeness

While talking with some Japanese people in an online form, someone said 日本語上手ですね！﻿ to me. I just replied そうですか, but what would be an appropriate way to reply keeping it as less informal as possible. Another important thing is that I believe the OP was being polite to me knowing that I am not a native instead of actually talking about my Japanese as I can speak about it for myself. So, I would like to know of any response more in the lines of *I'm humbled* or *I don't deserve* kind.

Comment: Or if you don't buy into the ridiculous Japanese mindset of denying every good thing, you could just say "thank you".

Comment: @istrasci I'd rather prefer not, because the Japanese have the habit of saying favorable things irrespective of the facts. I could probable be making a fool of myself. Besides, being a non-Westerner, thanking itself doesn't sound like a very reasonable response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There could be many ways of saying "I am not good at Japanese." depending on your personal preference and context. My favorites were

> いいえ、あまり[上手]{じょうず}ではありません。 No, I am not that good at Japanese.
>
> いいえ、あまり[上手]{じょうず}じゃないです。 Ditto
>
> いいえ、まだ[下手]{へた}です。 No, (my Japanese) is still poor.

いいえ is broadly used when you get praised to express modesty.

Answer (score 13):

The way to go is usually to just deny it a little.
Something in the lines of :

> そんな事ないです。
>   まだまだです。

Answer (score 9):

I would say:

> - そんなことないです。
> - 全然ですよ。
> - まだまだですよ。

Those means "not at all".

Answer (score 7):

Somewhat formal 「恐縮｛きょうしゅく｝です」 can be used to acknowledge a compliment with humility and modesty (like *I'm humbled*, I think) without necessarily denying the truth of it.  (In your case, busting out this phrase will probably reinforce their impression of your proficiency!)